# Heroku and the $HOME environment variable, can it be trusted?

Tags: heroku, environment-variables, buildpack

In the context of making a custom buildpack, I am looking for a reliable way to get the path to the deployed application's directory.

It seems the `$HOME` environment variable is set to `/app`, but I can't find any reference about this in the official documentation.

So, does Heroku guarantee that the directory referenced by `$BUILD_DIR` at compile time will be pointed by `$HOME` at run time?  If not, is there an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: I sadly don't know if they guarantee that `$HOME` always points there. 

But what I can say: in the >8 years I'm using Heroku, and in the >5 custom buildpacks we built, we always could rely on it.